# Hemingway: The Capital of the World

Tags: grammar

I´d like to know why Hemingway used in his short story this sentence:

> Before he had become ill he had been a very promising, even a sensational, fighter...

In my opinion, the sentence should be:

> Before he became ill he had been a very promising, even a sensational, fighter...

Why the two past perfects?

Answer (score 1):

The perfect *had become ill* is not obligatory, but Hemingway employs it to make it clear that the onset of the matador's illness occurred at a time well before Reference Time, the time at which the story is set. Like all the characters in the story except the boy Paco he has had time to become inured to his inadequacies and failures.